# Access UserService from Google Cloud Endpoint

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-endpoints

I am developing a Google App Engine app with a Cloud Endpoint.
My app uses OpenID to authenticate a user.
Once the user has logged in, in the same session, there is a call to the endpoint.
In the endpoint code I want to access the user service for the current logged in user.
This works on the development server, but after deploy to Google the userService returns null to the getCurrentUser() call.

Can I get the current logged in user during a cloud endpoint execution?

Answer (score 3):

You can't use the UserService within an Endpoint method (at least not one called via `/_ah/api`). Getting the current user in Endpoints is done via injection in the method signature, e.g.:

```
public Score insert(Score score, User user)
```

The `User` object will be populated with either: a valid user object (if the token sent into the request is valid) or `null` (if not).

I'm not sure how your local test is succeeding, but what I've described is the expected behavior.

Comment: Thank you for your quick response. I modified my method as you suggested and redeployed. I get the same null user object. I tested again on the local development server and the user object is valid.

Comment: `null` means your token is invalid. What client library are you using to make requests?

Comment: I'm not using a client library, just simply making a GET request using the browser instance used to authenticate into the session.

Comment: That's not going to work, built-in session management isn't used with Endpoints. You need to use OAuth to authenticate. See: https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/endpoints/auth

Comment: @DanHolevoet So, you are basically saying Endpoints is a really bad choice when building an app that is mostly used through a web browser where I do not want the user to have to login again every time the token expires?

Comment: @moin I'm not sure where I said that. OAuth 2 doesn't require the user to sign in more than once (subsequent requests can use immediate mode without user intervention).